# iOS | Photos App Like Photo Browser

Tags: ios, gallery, thumbnails

First of all, I do not want to create a simple 2 or 3 columns gallery. I need exactly like the screenshot of Photos App, I've attached to the question. Big image can be paginated, thumbnails ill be scrolled, selected image's thumbnail will be animated.

[image]

I have some ideas.

1st, I can use collection view for the thumbnail scroller. (I have already done that.) But big images' pagination and animation of the selected images thumbnail is the trick here.

2ns, I can use UIPageViewController for the big image, but how can I achieve the page control with the thumbs, it is the problem.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that observing the scroll view of the thumbnail's UICollectionView. UICollectionViewDelegate inherits from UIScrollViewDelegate, so you can receive notification of the scroll movements.

For every scroll position, check which cell is in the center point of the collection. As soon as that cell changes, you control the UIPageViewController.

Comment: I have already done that. Working -almost- perfectly (May some performance issues occur when I use this for video previews, but I can handle that.). But I need to do the thumbnail animations, especially when you are watching a video, if you check, video's thumbnail becomes much more larger and you can change the time by scrolling